# MySQL innodb_row_lock_time is more than wall clock time

Tags: innodb, locking, mysql-5.1, monitoring

We recently started graphing the **innodb_row_lock_time** status variable in our monitoring system.

I noticed something I can't understand on a graph for a busy server:

Between 04:55PM and 04:57PM, the value of this counter changed from **488,101,000** to **488,504,000**. The MySQL documentation says:

> innodb_row_lock_time
>   The total time spent in acquiring row locks, in milliseconds.

How is it possible that during those 2 minutes, the server spent **403,000 ms** in acquiring row locks? 2 minutes is only 120,000 ms

The only explanation that comes to mind is that this value is a sum of all threads but I cannot find any documentation to confirm this theory.

The server is MySQL 5.1

Comment: How many processors does your machine have?

Comment: The machine has 2 processors:
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz

Each has 8 cores / 16 threads

Comment: The factor of 2 (processors) * 8 (cores) * 2 (threads) (= 32 in total) could readily explain the apparent inconsistency in your times?

Comment: It could explain if the time is the sum of wait time of all threads but is it? This is what I'm trying to find out. The documentation doesn't say so was wondering if someone can confirm. I guess reading the source code would answer the question but I'm pretty sure I would get lost completely very quickly in MySQL src code.

Comment: I can't **prove** it for innodb_row_lock_time in particular, but this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/194756/cpu-basics-multiple-cpus-cores-and-hyper-threading-explained/) appears to suggest that it is the case! You pointed it out yourself - it's impossible to have more on the clock than elapsed time unless you have simultaneous execution of commands on different threads/cpus.

Answer (score 0):

This metric is cumulative. You have to take delta to see the change in amount of time. Then you have to divide by elapsed time to normalize it to say time waited per minute for example.